# Script to stop a program after a certain amount of time

Tags: python, beginner, timer

I created this script because the Spotify desktop app doesn't have a built in sleep timer, and I needed one. I made it as easy to use as possible, and it can close other programs because it asks for the package name at the beginning of the script.

```
import time
import sys
import subprocess

pkgname = input("Please set the package name: ")
tillclose = float(input("\nPlease choose the amount of time before it closes:\n\n[1.] 10 Minutes\n[2.] 30 Minutes\n[3.] 1 Hour\n[4.] 2 Hours\n[5.] 3 Hours\n[6.] 4 Hours\n[7.] 5 Hours\n"))

if tillclose == 1:
    print("Confirmed. Set to close in 10 Minutes.")
    tillclose = 600

    for remaining in range(int(tillclose), 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", pkgname])

elif tillclose == 2:
    print("Confirmed. Set to close in 30 Minutes.")
    tillclose = 1800

    for remaining in range(int(tillclose), 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", pkgname])

elif tillclose == 3:
    print("Confirmed. Set to close in 1 Hour.")
    tillclose = 3600

    for remaining in range(int(tillclose), 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", pkgname])

elif tillclose == 4:
    print("Confirmed. Set to close in 2 Hours.")
    tillclose = 7200

    for remaining in range(int(tillclose), 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", pkgname])

elif tillclose == 5:
    print("Confirmed. Set to close in 3 Hours")
    tillclose = 10800

    for remaining in range(int(tillclose), 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", pkgname])

elif tillclose == 6:
    print("Confirmed. Set to close in 4 Hours")
    tillclose = 14400

    for remaining in range(int(tillclose), 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", pkgname])

elif tillclose == 7:
    print("Confirmed. Set to close in 5 Hours")
    tillclose = 18000

    for remaining in range(int(tillclose), 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write("\r")
        sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)

    subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", pkgname])

else:
    print("Invalid option, please run again.")
```

It works flawlessly, but I'm wondering if there's a shorter way to make it.

Comment: Create one function with `tillclose` as the parameter and then call it.

Comment: in `for remaining in range(int(tillclose), 0, -1):` casting tillclose to an int seems to be redundant as it is already an int. I see you originally cast this to a float instead of an integer, there doesn't seem to be much point in that either so you might want to cast it originally to an int as `int(input("\nPlease choose the amount of time before it closes:\n\n[1.] 10 Minutes\n[2.] 30 Minutes\n[3.] 1 Hour\n[4.] 2 Hours\n[5.] 3 Hours\n[6.] 4 Hours\n[7.] 5 Hours\n"))`.

Comment: The first obvious thing on cursory examination is the repetition of code in all you elif statements. Surely all that can be put into a single function that is called in each elif.

Comment: As tillclose gets changed, you might aswell have a dictionary that maps each number to the new value for tillclose. e.g. `options = {1: 600, 2: 1800, ...}` etc, using `dict.get()` you can rewrite this code to be really clean.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import sys
import subprocess

pkgname = input("Please set the package name: ")
choice = float(input("\nPlease choose the amount of time before it closes:\n\n[1.] 10 Minutes\n[2.] 30 Minutes\n[3.] 1 Hour\n[4.] 2 Hours\n[5.] 3 Hours\n[6.] 4 Hours\n[7.] 5 Hours\n"))

secs_in_hour = 60 * 60
hour_intervals = [1/6, 1/2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# choice - 1 for options {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7} to index transition
tillclose = hour_intervals[int(choice) - 1] * secs_in_hour
for remaining in range(int(tillclose), 0, -1):
    sys.stdout.write("\r")
    sys.stdout.write("{:2d} seconds remaining.".format(remaining))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/F", "/IM", pkgname])
```

Comment: Bearing in mind that the OP asked "_if there's a shorter way to make it._" and it has since been migrated from Stack Overflow, can you please add a summary of the changes and benefits of this solution? It would likely be helpful to read (possibly first) [The help center page _How do I write a good answer?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).